# How do I add a Batch Normalization layer to my model in Flux.jl

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I have a simple model which I defined but I want it to use batch normalization so I don't have to calculate and provide the normalizations manually. The model currently looks like:

```
m = Chain(
  Dense(28^2, 64),
  Dense(64, 10),
  softmax)
```

How can I edit this model to add a BN layer or define a new one all together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Flux.jl's built in Batch Normalization function you can do the following:

```
m = Chain(
  Dense(28^2, 64),
  BatchNorm(64, relu),
  Dense(64, 10),
  BatchNorm(10),
  softmax)
```

where  `relu` is the element-wise activation that takes place after normalization. You can read why we use the `relu` function in an example like this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226923/why-do-we-use-relu-in-neural-networks-and-how-do-we-use-it. Find out more about the [`BatchNorm` function in the Flux.jl docs](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/layers/#Flux.BatchNorm).